# how to use onkeyup() method when i am writing my input with "text_field_tag" (ruby on rails)

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby

this is my form:

```
<%= form_tag('/search/results', :method => "get") do %>
  <%= label_tag(:q, "Search for:") %>
  <%= text_field_tag(:q) %> 
  <%= submit_tag("Search") %>
<% end %>
```

i want when i start typing in the text field the site wil refresh.
how can i do it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you mean to just add extra HTML attributes to the element generated by `text_field_tag`, you can pass them as a hash.

```
<%= text_field_tag(:q, :onkeyup => 'myJSFunctionToHandleStuff()') %>
```

Hash arguments other than `:disabled`, `:size`, `:maxlength`, `:placeholder` are treated just as passthrough HTML attributes onto the generated `input` element